# Time zones in MySQL with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5

I want to store a `Carbon` date time object in a MySQL Database and I am using **Laravel Eloquent** to do this.

I have build a test with different data types (`dateTime`, `dateTimeTz`, `timestamp` and `timestampTz` from Laravel Migrations) and every one cuts off the time zone and only stores the date and time. When the data is accessed again Laravel assumes the default time zone from `config` and I have invalid data.

Is there a way to either preserve the time zone or to automatically convert the date and time to UTC or the config time zone?

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: It's worth noting that MySQL itself doesn't offer the required facilities. The closest it has is `TIMESTAMP` columns, which are stored as UTC. No idea if Laravel does the required stuff though.

Comment: Unfortunately the `timestamp` column type is even worse. It stores in UTC which seems nice but the conversion happens according to the session time zone and if hat is not set deliberately to the correct time zone everything is messed up even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't provide any features to store `Timestamp` with `Timezone`. You have to separately maintain all the timezone manually.

You can define seprate column for maintaining the timezone when the `Timestamp` retrieved from the Database you can convert `Timestamp` to related  `Timezone`.

For that you can use Laravel features `Accessors`.

Comment: I guess that is currently the best way to use `datetime` fields in MySQL and convert everything to UTC through an `accessor`.